# Javascript does not work at colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

*Pop-ups* are output at *datalab* but not at the *colaboratory*.

```
test = """
<script type="text/Javascript">
alert("hi")
</script>
"""
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(test)
```

Is it a *colaboratory* bug? How can I pop up normally?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a bug. Each output is rendered in an `iframe` sandbox, and the sandbox doesn't have the popup capability.

A simple work-around is to use something like `raw_input` to prompt the user, e.g.,

```
value = raw_input('Enter value: ')
print 'entered', value
```

Comment: I do not know what you mean. *colaboratory* and *dataLab* appear to be the same engine. But why does not it work only on a *colaboratory*?

Comment: Do you have a better UI design than just raw_input?

For example, I want to do some interaction like multiple choices a few times. Then use those choices to calculate something.

Comment: @KorakotChaovavanich The purpose of the **MNIST** example is to use a layout in JavaScript.

Comment: @JaeyeonBaek Is it this one? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-dist-mnist-example/blob/master/notebooks/Online%20prediction%20example.ipynb